# sound not playing in jar

Tags: java, jar, javasound

I have packed all the class files and resources as a jar but on execution the sound files wont play. My package structure is:

```
+project
|_classes
|_ _*.class
|_resources
|_ _ *.jpg,*.wav
```

Code:

```
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(kidsClassRoom.class.getResourceAsStream("../resources/"+file));
```

getting a `null` when this line is executed!!

Answer (score 2):

An alternate theory to those already presented.  Often successful getResource() calls depend on the class loader instance that is called to locate them.  For this reason, I would recommend to use an instance of a user defined object, from which to call getResource().  E.G.

```
// Sanity check
System.out.println("The value of 'file' is: " + file);
// Presuming kidsClassRoom1 is an instance of kidsClassRoom
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.
    getAudioInputStream(
        kidsClassRoom1.
            getClass().
            getResourceAsStream("/resources/"+file));
```

You might also note that snippet uses the prefix of "/" for the resource.  Contrary to what others are saying, I am confident that means 'from the root' of the resource path, in whatever Jar on the run-time class-path it is found.  Leaving the '/' or '../' out will have the class loader searching for the resource in a sub-path of the class that this is occurring in.

Of course - make sure the Wav ends up in the Jar!  Copy/rename the .jar to a .zip and double click it is the 'quick & dirty' way to examine the archive contents on Windows.

Comment: can you explain why kidsClassRoom1.getClass() is better than kidsClassRoom.class?

Comment: I am not certain it is.  There are different class loaders.  The bootstrap class loader used to load things from the J2SE will not discover classes or resources on the application's run-time class-path.  The best class loader for finding app. resources is a context class loader.  The use of className.class **might** produce the context class loader, and might not.  OTOH using an actual object instance of a custom class guarantees the context class loader is used.  But most important of all - does this advice work for you?  Is the wav file 'found'?

Comment: kidsClassRoom.class way worked for me. The problem was I had given a wrong file name!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a package named `resources` as shown below 
[image]

then

```
 AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(kidsClassRoom.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/"+file));
```

Comment: No any folder `Foo` will do , but then `kidsClassRoom.class.getResourceAsStream("Foo/"+file)`

Comment: just open jar file in any archiver tool and put the snapshot here, i want to check structure

Comment: I am asking about jar's snapshot when it is opened in some archiever to check dir structure that has been packed

Comment: There is no resource dir inside jar. :) how did you pack it ?

Comment: inside classes dir: `jar -cmvf0 manif.txt kidsClassRoom.jar *.class ../resources/*.*`

Comment: from the above.above screen shot you have given it seems resources is directly inside classes so go for it `jar -cf kidsClassRoom.jar *.class ./resources/*.*`

Comment: had two mistakes: one was file name was wrong and the other is which you pointed. that resources wasn't inside jar. Got it working now. thanks :)

Comment: jar -cf kidsClassRoom.jar *.class `.`/resources/*.* what does the dot mean here? and i used just 'resources' this time to get the folder inside the jar. what's the difference?

Comment: `dot` means current directory, I have that habit due to linux, its good to specify that you can visulize that

Answer (score 1):

This is my function for playing a looping sound file in jars, it works fine for me.

It appears that `getResourceAsStream()` doesn't work with jars. however, `getResource()` does.

```
public synchronized void alarm() {
    try {
        crit = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("critical.wav"));
        crit.open(inputStream1);
        crit.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `getResourceAsStream`, it is not relative to the current class, but the root of the archive. That is, first try to remove `../`.

Comment: Try right-clicking on the resources folder and select "Build Path -> Use as source folder". (This is just to make sure that the files are accessible to the class-loader when launching from eclipse.)

Comment: I am not using any IDE now :)

Comment: Aha, I see, then make sure the folder is part of the class path (use the `-cp resources:bin` if your classes are located in bin. (Use `;` instead of `:` if you're on windows.)

Comment: When you do getResourceAsStream, it is not relative to the current class, `but the root of the archive`. That is, first try to remove ../.   which will be the root folder?

Comment: Ah, good question. I believe it searches each folder of the class path in the order they appear in the `-cp`-argument.

Comment: If you wont mind can you please tell how/where do I use this `-cp resources:bin`. I haven't used jar before :)

Comment: Aha, I missread, I didn't realize that you've packaged it in a jar. Then it should work without messing with the class-path. The class-loader should search the archive based on the root of the archive.

Comment: got it working. see other comment for the problem I had. thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note is that in the exported jar the resources are not stored as files (Read this somewhere, someone more knowledgeable please input). So it's best to get the resource as a URL Object first then pass that to the AudioInputStream Object.

```
URL url = YourClass.class.getResource(filename);
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

If the resource is in a subfolder, remember to add it to your filename path.