# Audio Player in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I am new to J2ME. I want to play an audio song in my application. I have written

```
       Player p = null;

    try {           
        p = Manager.createPlayer(getClass().getResourceAsStream("aa.wav"),"audio/x-wav");
        p.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MediaException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where "aa.wav" is a wav format song placed in resource folder. when i debug this code

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("aa.wav")
```

it returns null.

Can you please Help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

if resource folder is under src then.

make it

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/aa.wav")
```

Comment: song is in res folder. I have written "/res/aa.wav" but still it doesn't work.

Comment: make sure `res` is under `src`

Comment: I meant `res` should be a `package` , exactly check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923907/sound-not-playing-in-jar#4923945)